# Where do you get data to populate a suggest-box with Country, State, City and Zip Information?

Tags: forms, geolocation

I'm trying to create some dialogs in my web-app that can auto-suggest possible Countries, States, Cities and Zips in a form.

I was planning on storing this information in a database, and making calls to it from AJAX as the user types.

I don't want anything overly complicated like the Geonames database that I was offered when I asked this question over at the [GIS stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17178/good-place-to-get-country-state-city-and-zipcode-information).

I installed the Geonames database on my mysql server, but I found that it was more like points on the map (things like schools, stores etc) than it was just individual Countries, States, Cities and Zipcodes.

Please let me know if I am oversimplifying the problem, as it's entirely possible that I am.

Comment: I think we need more info from you about how you're planning on auto-populating these fields. Is it based on GeoIP info? Are you trying to calculate it based on a partial address? Are you using proximity to a known address/zip? Are you mapping a phone number/area code to city/zip? Or are you just autocompleting based on what the user types?

Comment: I'd say using a proximity to a known address/zip.  I want to group together locations (i.e. Country, State, City and Zip) that a user enters so they can be identified between multiple records as the same location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One source is [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities). I haven't looked at their data, so I can comment on how good it is.

You *will* still need to make a decision about what to do if the exising, real-world city is not in your database.

Comment: Note the important bit of the license agreement: 

All advertising materials and documentation mentioning features or use of this database must display the following acknowledgment:
"This product includes data created by MaxMind, available from
http://www.maxmind.com/"

Comment: On the whole though it looks pretty good! :) Thanks!

Also opening this file is kind of a pain, but this thread solves it, since it's double zipped: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129771

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want a valid, accurate address from the user. Each country varies widely, but in the USA, the USPS maintains a current database of valid addresses, and everything you can possibly imagine about them. Vendors of *proper* address verification products (that can validate and standardize wrong/incomplete addresses) are CASS-Certified by the USPS.

There are a few options for doing what you want to do. The easiest of all, and most affordable (even free) is an address validation API. I work at a company called [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com) which offers such an API called LiveAddress. There's a simple Javascript implementation you can just copy+paste into your website. As the user submits the form, they'll be prompted to choose a valid address based on what they typed. I am sure this will be of some use to you.

Comment: That would be a good thing to use to ensure the validity of the database, thank you for adding it.   What I really want to be able to do is associate a record (an address) with a particular City, State, and Zip so that I can search for records associated with a particular City, State or Zip.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://www.opensourcecf.com/1/2007/02/Determining-Zip-Code-Proximity.cfm) on a Coldfusion blog explains one implementation of what I think you're trying to do. It's pretty straight forward:

1. He found a cheap paid (regularly updated) source that provides their app with up-to-date city/zip/state/geo-coordinate records and imported it into an SQL database.
2. He created a user-defined function that would measure the distance between two sets of long/lat coordinates.
3. Then use the UDF to perform queries to find locations within a particular distance or check the distance between two locations.